# BTC sent to Coinbase BCH wallet

Tags: bitcoin-cash, coinbase.com

I have sent my BTC to a BCH wallet on Coinbase, it is for a sizable amount of money and I read that if greater than $5K, they will help you.  What is the proper channel to ask for help as the cases I have opened are not getting any results.  Both accounts are mine one on Electrum (BTC) and one on Coinbase (BCH)

Answer (score 0):

Coinbase has the private key for the BTC transaction (because it should be the same as the BCH address), but it might require manual intervention on their part to recover the deposit and refund it. Unfortunately, their support is swamped with many other issues this month. If you submitted a support ticket to https://support.coinbase.com/, you might just have to wait a while before they get to it.

Comment: I am fine to wait as long as it is not gone forever, $15K is a lot to lose.

Comment: Unfortunately, still no guarantees that you'll hear from support any time soon. Their response times are pretty abysmal right now.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Ryan I did a similar mistake. But when I contacted Coinbase they just said due to irreversible nature of crypto currencies transactions they cannot do anything about it. Do you know if this is a routine process and at some point in time they will get to intervene and transfer private keys or their reply means there is no hope and coins are lost? Are you aware of any simple similar incidents that were resolved?

Comment: If your "similar" mistake was identical to Jeff's, then what they said is not accurate. It is reversible; although, it is likely a burden for them. These kinds of mistakes are really dangerous to make. You really need to be careful when submitting any kind of cryptocurrency transfer nowadays, especially with forks that use the same address format.  Yes, I have heard of similar incidents being resolved on Reddit, but I also heard that Coinbase requires the USD value to be over $5000 for them to intervene; though, I do not have any first hand experience with this.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Yes identical sent 2 BTC from blockchain so I fall into 5k$+ category. I always take extra caution but this happened on 21st of Dec and Coinbase just had launched BCH wallet and I was not aware of it so by mistake ended up on that wallet. Hope they do help at some point. So far no customer support and only negative responses.